# Como decriptografar email criptografado em SHA-256?

Tags: java, java-ee, criptografia

Estou criptografando um email e guardando no banco, como faço para decriptografar esse mesmo email que foi criptografado.

Segue o código que usei para criptografar.

```
public String getEmailCriptografado(String email){
    email = email.toLowerCase();
    email = Normalizer.normalize(email, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    pattern.matcher(email).replaceAll("");

    String emailCritptografado = "";

    try {
        MessageDigest algoritmo = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        try {
            byte messageDigest[] = algoritmo.digest((email)
                    .getBytes("UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

            for (byte b : messageDigest) {
                hexString.append(String.format("%02X", 0xFF & b));
            }

            emailCritptografado = hexString.toString();
            System.out.println(emailCritptografado);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return emailCriptografado;
}
```

Existe alguma forma de decriptografar nessa maneira?

Comment: Tenho a impressão que você não criptografou, mas sim gerou um hash. E hash desse tipo é feito pra não ser reversível. Normalmente o hash é usado para gerar a chave que vai criptografar a mensagem, e não para ser aplicado no conteúdo da mesma.

Comment: SHA-256 é um hash. Não se pode reverter pois essa é a natureza de um hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não é possível. SHA-256 é uma função *hash* e como tal ela é "one way", após a conversão não há volta, não existe processo de "descriptografar". Se por algum motivo você quer encriptar os emails no banco (isso é algo bem incomum em, veja se é realmente necessário) deve procurar alguma função de encriptação "two way" que permita reversão.